# Want data off broken phone. Possible?

Tags: samsung

The screen of my samsung S6edge is showing black but the rest of the lights work if i push the hardware buttons. I don't seem to be able to get my touch screen to respond at all.

The autobackup wasn't able to work while I was away because it never had access to WiFi.

Is there any way that i can pull my photos off it? I have a mac with dual boot windows and am happy to add a linux boot if that will make my life easier.

Comment: What happens if you connect the phone to PC via cable?

Comment: I tried that but my computer doesn't even recognise my phone's existance

Comment: And previously it was recognized?

Comment: And what is with your phone's screen? Damaged? Broken? Why it is black?

Comment: You can have not only screen broken but also internal memory, if your phone experienced hard accident.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on whether or not you enabled Developer Options in Settings before you lost use of the touch screen. Try downloading Samsung USB drivers for PC and install on computer or laptop, turn phone on and connect to PC with *data* cable. If it installs, you can list folders from your phone and copy files.

Answer (score 0):

You could buy a cheap USB to HDMI converter and connect the phone to a tv/monitor. When you can see the screen, try and see if the touch screen works.

If the touch screen doesn't work, you can connect a mouse to the phone using a micro USB OTG hub, and also connect the HDMI to a USB port (if you bought a micro USB to HDMI converter you'll need a micro USB to USB adapter too)

Example of items. Note: I can't guarantee this will work. 
http://m.ebay.com/itm/351932566559
http://m.ebay.com/itm/Hot-USB-3-0-to-HDMI-Converter-Cable-Display-Graphic-Adapter-for-HDTV-1080P-/122176138189